# Can't access variable in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I new to nodejs. I have read many articles and can't figure out what is wrong with the following code. Its giving error checkForActivity is not defined. Any help would be grateful.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(sock){
    var checkForActivity = false;
    sock.on('data',function(data){
       changeCheckForActivity();
    });
});

function changeCheckForActivity(){
    checkForActivity = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checkForActivity` is defined only in the scope of `createServer()`. In  `changeCheckForActivity()`, it is not yet defined if `createServer()` is async and anyways not visible.

```
var net = require('net');
var checkForActivity = false;
net.createServer(function(sock){
    sock.on('data',function(data){
       changeCheckForActivity();
    });
});

function changeCheckForActivity(){
    checkForActivity = true;
}
```

probably a better solution would be:

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(sock){
    changeCheckForActivity(false);
    sock.on('data',function(data){
       changeCheckForActivity(true);
    });
});

function changeCheckForActivity(isAct){
    // do something in reaction to activity
    // isAct is now a local replacement for 
    // checkForActivity 
}
```

Comment: Actually i want that variable for each socket, there is some logic dependent on that variable.

Comment: `function(data){
       changeCheckForActivity();
    });` is already a callback

Comment: check out the second version that gets rid of `checkForActivity`

Answer (score 1):

`checkForActivity` is defined in a function and therefore it's in that functions [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Within the scope for function `changeCheckForActivity()` `checkForActivity` has not been defined. If you define `checkForActivity` outside of the function, it will be accessible by both functions:

```
var net = require('net');    
var checkForActivity = false;
net.createServer(function(sock){
    sock.on('data',function(data){
        changeCheckForActivity();
    });
});

function changeCheckForActivity(){
    checkForActivity = true;
}
```